# jQuery SlideUp on a row with hidden columns

Tags: jquery, html-table, hidden, slideup

I've got a table and when I remove a row it animates with slideUp.

```
$(id).find("td div").slideUp
```

I used this trick to use slideUp on a row : [animating-table-rows-with-jquery](http://thefrontiergroup.com.au/blog/2008/12/animating-table-rows-with-jquery/)

There is no problem when all columns are displayed, but when I have hidden columns, it just removes the row with no animation. I guess it is a normal behaviour from slideUp, but is there a trick to make it work with animate? I was thinking of testing if the td is hidden, do nothing, else slideUp, but I don't think this will do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this is that the callback given to `slideUp` is not called after *all* animations are complete, but after *each* animation is complete. Since the `div`s in the hidden column aren't visible, the sliding up animation doesn't need to happen, i.e. is completed immediately, and thus the callback is called immediately.

The callback, however, removes the *whole row*.

There are several ways to deal with this. The idea that you had yourself (not dealing with `div`s that aren't visible anyway) is one way that should work.

Another way is to set a time out to remove the row, instead of doing it in the callback.

A third way is to check in the callback if there are any `div`s left, and only remove the row if there are not, i.e. something like

```
$(id).find("td div").slideUp(function() {
    $(this).remove();                     // remove the div itself
    if ($(id).find("td div").length == 0) // if none are left
        $(id).remove();                   // then remove the row
});
```

Comment: Really nice answer, I will test this tomorrow (end of working day for me ;), and post the solution I've chosen. Thanks a lot (btw I'm really interested in learning how animations work in jQuery, where did you find such information ?).

Comment: @Michael Lumbroso: I guess everyone doing animation with jQuery has been bitten by a similar problem at some point; you then learn that kind of stuff along the way. The [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/) is actually pretty good.

Comment: I have implemented your solution, it worked so perfectly, thanks for your clear, exhaustive and supra fast answer, I will register to be able to vote for you ;)

Btw, I checked the jQuery doc before submitting my answer (always do before creating a topic ^^), but I hadn't found any of what could have helped me with this. I checked again, and I still don't know how i could have gotten any more useful information without your valuable pro explainations. (sry for my bad English, Grammatical conjugation is not my specialty :p )

Comment: @Michael Lumbroso: Thanks, glad it worked. The relevant part in the [documenation of slideUp](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/) is *If multiple elements are animated, it is important to note that the callback is executed once per matched element, not once for the animation as a whole.*